# jQuery DataTables with custom headers to fetch Server Side Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, datatables

Is there a way to use with jQuery Datatables a custom ajax header to fetch server side Data?

what I try but do not sends back any response(checked server side the data is getting properly generated)

```
oTable = $('#saleReport').dataTable({
  "ajax": {
            //"url": "/reports",
            "method": "post",
            "headers": { 'X-OCTOBER-REQUEST-HANDLER': 'onReports' }         
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is not possible. I look at dt library and don't see this option. You can edit the library for your feature.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - headers

https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js

line 2437

======
EDIT
======

is possible via function fnServerData. Before send you can use headers.

Soulution found at http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/17063/how-to-add-authorization-header-to-ajax-requests

documentation
http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnServerData

Comment: thanks for feedback I will search forward for a solution